Logback - Proper way to create custom json with string logs and application logs
I am trying to create a custom log format because my app was running into Wildfly and I have migrated it to SpringBoot. On Wildfly the application log was already in a JSON format but If I use a simple pattern like the example abose, I lose important messages from SpringBoot, errors and output is a mess mixing plain string and a json:
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

My app code is simple, when try to log it basically does:
MyLogObject log = ...
logger.info(log);

On MyLogObject has an override on toString() using Jackson to return a formatted JSON.
Based on that, I have changed it to use net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder with a custom pattern:
<pattern>
    {
    "timestamp": "%date{ISO8601}",
    "level": "%level",
    "thread": "%t",
    "message": "#tryJson{%message}"
    }
</pattern>

It almost solved my problem but now I feel that I'm missing some not handled exceptions and message is mixing a String and a nested JSON.
Now I am writing a class extending AbstractFieldJsonProvider and it looks like to solve all my problems but I don't feel this is right because I am checking if message starts with a { then I convert it back to my MyLogObject and start to write fields:
generator.writeStringField("_logType", "MyApp");
generator.writeStringField("_message", "Transaction saved");
...

What is the proper to avoid mix string and json on message fields? Should I drop the MyLogObject? Is there any other way to log spring stuff in same format of my application log?

Possible Solutions:
Use Logback with JSON format:
Spring Boot uses Logback by default for logging, and you can configure it to log in JSON format.
You can customize the logging in Spring Boot by modifying the logback-spring.xml file to include JSON formatting.
Example logback-spring.xml configuration:

<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>
            {"timestamp":"%date{ISO8601}", "level":"%level", "logger":"%logger", "message":"%message", "exception":"%ex"}
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</root>

Tip:
If you prefer JSON-only logging to avoid mixing plain text and JSON, it’s best to configure your logs to be entirely in JSON format, especially if you're using log aggregation tools like the ELK Stack or Splun
If the problem persists, please share the specific error message you're encountering, and I can help you troubleshoot it further.
